# Angular JSON data returning undefined (ERROR TypeError) during onInit and afterViewInit

Tags: json, angular, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular and I have a JSON data of `categories` and `subcategories` that I get in my `navbar` component. I have a dropdown `categorydetail` component that accepts a `Category` object and the `subcategories` JSON response so it can match the subcategories that match with the Category ID. The `categories` JSON gets rendered fine, but the `subcategories` is inconsistent. It sometimes gets returned correctly (as an object) and sometimes it is returned undefined. I've tried different lifecycle hooks but I just can't seem to get it to return consistently.

---

**navbar.component.html**

```html
<div>
    <ul id="navLinks" class="flex-row linklist">
        <li *ngFor="let category of categories.data">
            <a href="#">{{category.name}}</a>
            <div id="navDropdown">
                <div class="container flex-row">
                    <app-categorydetails [category]="category" [subcategory]="subcategories"></app-categorydetails>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoriesService } from '../categories.service';
import { CategoryList } from 'src/assets/models/categories';
import { SubcategoriesService } from '../subcategories.service';
import { SubcategoryList } from 'src/assets/models/subcategories';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class NavbarComponent {
  categories!: any;
  subcategories!: any;

  constructor(private CategoriesService: CategoriesService, 
              private SubcategoriesService: SubcategoriesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // load JSONs
    this.categories = this.CategoriesService.getCategories().subscribe((data:CategoryList) => {
      this.categories.success = data.success;
      this.categories.message = data.message;
      this.categories.data = data.data;
    });

    this.subcategories = this.SubcategoriesService.getSubcategories().subscribe((data:SubcategoryList) => {
      this.subcategories.success = data.success;
      this.subcategories.message = data.message;
      this.subcategories.data = data.data;
    });
  }
}
```

**categorydetails.component.html**

```html
<img class="img-adaptive" src="https://picsum.photos/240/300">
<div id="navDropdownLinks" class="flex-row">
    <div>
        <strong><p>NEW IN {{category.name.toUpperCase()}}</p></strong>
        <div *ngIf="subcategories">
            <ul class="linklist">
               <li *ngFor="let item of subcategories"><a href="#"><h3>{{item.name}}</h3></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<img class="img-adaptive" src="https://picsum.photos/240/300">
```

**categorydetails.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryList, Category } from 'src/assets/models/categories';
import { Subcategory, SubcategoryList } from 'src/assets/models/subcategories';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categorydetails',
  templateUrl: './categorydetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categorydetails.component.css']
})
export class CategorydetailsComponent {

  @Input() category!: Category;
  @Input() subcategory!: SubcategoryList;
  subcategories: Subcategory[] = [];


  constructor() {}
  // following an answer on another thread here on SO about setting a delay but I still get undefined at times
  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout((_:any) => this.load());
  }

  // tried AfterViewInit but still inconsistent
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   //setTimeout((_:any) => this.load());
  }

  load(): void {
    // load passed JSON data
    console.log(this.subcategory.data);
    this.subcategories = this.subcategory.data.filter((item: Subcategory) => {
        return item.main_category == this.category.name;
    });
  }
}
```

I've tried assigning the `load()` function to both ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit but both have been returning undefined at times. There are times that it works but I would like it to work all the time. I've also had a version where the function was bound to a `mousemove` event on the parent `li`, it works with no issues which makes me think that I might be calling the function too early. I want the data to be loaded without intervention from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assigning it in ngOnInit is correct, but you shouldn't subscribe, you should pipe and map instead. then subscribe it in html instead using async pipe.

also your input to child component should be a stream instead of categories as well.

here's a good article to read
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-step-by-step-understanding-async-pipe